# как в qt сравнить две строки

Tags: qt, qstring

как в qt   сравнить две строки  (QString)

если так сравнивать, то всё ок

```
int main(int argv, char **args)
 {
    QString str1="1005",str2="1006";
    if(str1 == str2)
        qDebug()<<" тут не напечатается ";
    qDebug()<<"всё ок ";

}
```

вывод

```
всё ок
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот как я сравниваю строки

```
int x = QString::compare(str1, str2, Qt::CaseInsensitive);  // если строки равны, x должен вернуть 0
```